# diff and patch using wrong line ending when creating new files or line end changed

Tags: diff, patch, newline, eol, lf

I'm trying to create a patch using diff, but I can't get the patch to use the line end characters used in the files when creating a new file or to change the line ending when the file changes it.  Basically, I'm doing:

```
cp -r dir1 dir3
diff -ruN dir1 dir2 > dir3\patch.txt
cd dir3
patch -p1 < patch.txt
```

All the changes between `dir1` and `dir2` properly apply, except the end of line character for new files is defaulting to `CR+LF`, even where the file in `dir2` uses `LF` as an end of line marker.  Also, any files where the difference between them is just a line end change are not patched in any way -- diff doesn't seem to see any change.

So running `diff -rq dir2 dir3` gives a bunch of `Files aaa and bbb differ`, but `diff -rwq dir2 dir3` works fine.

I'm using `diff - GNU diffutils version 2.7` and `patch 2.5` from `UnxUtils` on Windows XP.

Is there any way to make new and changed files included in the patch keep the line ending from the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
cp -r dir1 dir3
diff --binary -ruN dir1 dir2 > dir3\patch.txt
cd dir3
patch --no-backup-if-mismatch --binary -u -p1 < patch.txt
```

Not using the `--binary` flag means that the file is parsed line by line, ignoring EOL. For some reason, it won't always patch cleanly (gives a `Hunk #1 succeeded at 1 with fuzz 1.` message) so I had to include `--no-backup-if-mismatch` to prevent it making `.orig` files. The `-u` seems to be optional, since patch will figure the patch type out on it's own.